# Symfony 4+, Is it better to use container->get or to inject service into controller?

Tags: symfony

I am wondering what is the best way to use services in controllers in Symfony 4+.

A controller inheriting from AbstractController can access the ->container->get("service_name") function to retrieve the needed service.
The second possibility is to inject the needed services directly into the controller through the services.yml file. The autowiring feature will easily give the service to the controller's constructor without any extra configuration.

Both approaches seem to work well, what is the cleanest way ?

Comment: Ref: *["Use Dependency Injection to Get Services"](https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices.html#use-dependency-injection-to-get-services)*

Comment: Sure, both are possible for common services. Is one solution better than the other ? according to future versions compatibility ? according to SF global philosophy ?

Comment: The link points to `The Symfony Framework Best Practices`, authored by the symfony team. I'm implying that, when they suggest using dependency injection instead of `container->get`, you should probably follow suit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dependency injection gives you type-hinted dependencies, which is significantly better than fetching services from container with alias strings. Type-hinting allows you to discover bugs a lot earlier than you would otherwise.

Since php is moving towards being more type-hinted programming language ([PHP 7.4 - Typed properties](https://php.watch/versions/7.4/typed-properties)) it is clear that dependency injection is a way to go.

Comment: Sure, that is a great argument. The strong typing is an important part of the future orientations of PHP. It is also more present in Symfony. This way, even the common services should be better accessed through the dependency injection rather than the container.